# Knockout JS: Value passed to Writeable Computed returns [object Object]?

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, ko.observablearray

#### Background

While working on an ongoing learning project, I noticed that I require a writeable computed function to solve a problem I'm facing. Here's the skinny:  I'm trying to 1) drop a user-specified number of assignments scores 2) of a user specified type from a gradebook.

The user inputs the value above, then click a button, `dropLowestScores`. The code then adds the lowest scores to an array called 'lowest', which exists on each `student` object. 
Then, observable `mean`s on each student are updated based on new values, dropping the lowest ones.

#### Problem

My problem comes to life when I try to drop. I'm not confident that my writeable computed is structured correctly, but I'm not sure what's wrong either.  I noticed that that properties 'n' and `workType` are correctly given in my `read` function, but in my `write`, they are not as desired. In `read`, for example, `workType` returns default value, `homework`, but in my `write` function, it returns `[object Object]`.

Responses that can clarify what my problem is and give me a strategy for correctly scripting a writeable computed would be appreciated.

Relevant JS and HTML snippets follow.

> **JSBin**:  [Full Project](http://jsbin.com/fehoq/193/edit)

#### JS

```
this.dropLowestScores = ko.computed({

    // read the parameters necessary to write values to property 'lowest'

    read: function() {

        // user sets value of 'n' in the page via ko 'options'

        var n = _this.n().n;

        // user selects 'workType' from list of ko options            

        var workType = _this.workType().workType;
        console.log("workType:" + workType);
        return n,workType;   
    },

    // now use current parameter values to set new values to 'lowest' arrays 

    write: function(n,workType) {
        //this.n = n;
        //this.workType = workType;

        // 'lowest' exists as a property for each student, 
        // ergo, I loop through each student 

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(_this.students(), function(student){
            var i = _this.students.indexOf(student);

            console.log("_this.assignments: " + _this.assignments()[i].workType().workType);
            console.log("this.workType: " + this.workType);
            console.log(_this.assignments()[i].workType().workType == this.workType);

            // if the current assignment is the same as the user-specified assignment, 
            //add the score for that assignment to array 'tmp'; then set lowest = tmp 

            if(_this.assignments()[i].workType().workType == this.workType){
                var tmp = student.scores().sort(_this.comparator).slice(0,this.n);
                console.log(tmp.length);
                student.lowest(tmp);
            }    
        });
    }
});
```

#### HTML

```
<button data-bind="click: dropLowestScores">Drop Lowest Scores</button>
```

Currently, I just have the above function bound to a butten. Ideally, this is how I'd leave it. Other properties referenced, such as `n`, `workType`, and `mean` are input in a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel silly now, but it turns out I was on the right track; indeed, the solution was trivially simple. In the `read` function, I just needed to define properties in the following way:`this.variable = ...` as opposed to `var variable = ...`.

```
this.dropLowestScores = ko.computed({

    // read the parameters necessary to write values to property 'lowest'

    read: function() {

        // user sets value of 'n' in the page via ko 'options'

        this.n = _this.n().n;

        // user selects 'workType' from list of ko options            

        this.workType = _this.workType().workType;

        console.log("workType:" + workType);
        return n,workType;   
    },

    ...
```